# Why is the output not right even tho im using 'long' data type here?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long x, y;
        
    printf("Enter the first number: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &x);
    
    printf("Enter the second number: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &y);
    
    long z = x + y;
    
    printf("The answer is: %ld \n", z);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I can't add more than 4 billion here even though i should since im using 'Long' datatype here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEsC1.png)

Comment: On Windows `long` and `int` are the same width. On other platforms `long` may be larger. You can check this with `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)`.

Answer (score 2):

`long` may hold 32 or 64-bits, depending on the system. It appears your system uses 32-bits. Also, since `long` is signed, the maximum value `long` can take is `2**31 - 1` (< 4 billion).

You can instead use

- `unsigned long`, which can take values up to `2**32 - 1` (> 4 billion), or
- `long long`/`unsigned long long`, guaranteed to work with at least 64-bits.

You'll also want to change the corresponding format strings to `%lu`/`%lld`/`%llu`.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for your comment. I forgot how nuanced the standard is regarding `long`.

Comment: And thanks for updating your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The allowed range for `long` may be as small as [-2,147,483,647 ... +2,147,483,647].  This can occur when `long` is 32-bit.

`long` may be wider, like 64-bit, and then handle a range of [-9,223,372,036,854,775,807 ... 9,223,372,036,854,775,807].

To certainly handle values like 4 billion, use `long long` which is at least 64-bit.

```
long long x, y;
printf("Enter the first number: \n");
scanf("%lld", &x);
printf("Enter the second number: \n");
scanf("%lld", &y);

long long z = x + y;
printf("The answer is: %lld \n", z);
```

---

More nuanced code may what to use `unsigned long` to handle [0 ... 4,294,967,295] or types like `int64_t`, `int_least64_t`...